# How to Do array.map between two numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

let assume I have array

```
arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

so I want iterate based on two value one is index, and offset
, for example, `index=2`, `offet=5` 
expected output

```
newArray=[3,4,5,6,7]
```

I tried .slice but it is not meet the requirement

Comment: `arr.slice(2, 6).map((element, index)=>console.log(element, index)})`

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].splice(2,5))
```

Comment: this approach mutates the array. this is not a side effect, but the real purpose of [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Answer (score 2):

You need for [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) as second parameter an index, not the length of the part. Just add the index as well.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    index = 2,
    offset = 5,
    result = array.slice(index, index + offset);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

> arr.slice([begin[, end]])

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let index = 2, offset = 5

console.log(arr.slice(index, index + offset))
```

Using [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let index = 2, offset = 5

console.log(Array.from(arr).splice(index, offset))
```

Answer (score 0):

slice() should meet your requirements:

```
Array.prototype.slice(index, index + offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `slice()` like this and then iterate the result using the standard `map()` method of Array

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
arr.slice(2, 6).map((element, index)=>console.log(element, index));
```